# Can't mass-assign protected attributes when import data from csv file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, csv, import

I have a form for import data like this:

```
<%= form_tag({ controller: 'courses', action: :import }, multipart: true) do %> 
  <%= label_tag 'file', 'Import data' %>
  <%= file_field_tag 'file' %>
  <%= submit_tag "Import", name: nil, class: 'btn' %>
<% end %>
```

This is my import action:

```
def import
  require 'csv'

  csv_text = File.read(params[:file].tempfile.to_path.to_s)
  csv = CSV.parse(csv_text, headers: true )
  csv.each do |row|
    row = row.to_hash.with_indifferent_access
    Course.create(row.to_hash.symbolize_keys)
  end
  flash[:success] = "Successfully import data."
  redirect_to courses_url
end
```

But when i choose a file and press button `Import` in browser, i got error:

```
ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error in CoursesController#import
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: Name, Code
```

In my `Course` model, `name` and `code` already are attr_accessible:

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :code, :name
end
```

What's wrong with my code?

**Updated**
This is my csv file:

```
name, code
ERP System, HT555DV01
Data Mining, HT459DV01
```

**New code to create data**

```
csv.each do |row|
  Course.create!(name: row[0], code: row[1])
end
```

Comment: Add a line attr_accessor :code, :name and then re-run the whole process and revert back.

Comment: it make same error, and also invisible all name and code of my courses in index page too :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
csv.each do |row|
  row = row.to_hash.with_indifferent_access
  Course.create(row.to_hash.symbolize_keys)
end
```

replace to

```
  csv.each do |row|
    Course.create(row.to_hash)
  end
```

**Update**

```
csv_file = File.read(params[:file].tempfile.to_path.to_s)
csv = CSV.parse(csv_file, :headers => true) 
csv.each do |row|
   Course.create!(:name => row[0], :code => row[1])    
end
```

**Update 2**

```
csv_file = params[:file].read
CSV.parse(csv_file) do |row|
   course = Course.create(row)
   course.save
end
```

source => 
http://www.funonrails.com/2012/01/csv-file-importexport-in-rails-3.html
http://erikonrails.snowedin.net/?p=212

Comment: it now has other error: `ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError in CoursesController#import` `unknown attribute: Name`

Comment: Your first updated works, but `headers` should be `true`, because i have first row is column name. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

Try `Course.create(row.to_hash.symbolize_keys, :without_protection => true)` or even combine it with Dipak's suggestion.

Alternatively, I would prefer `Course.create!(name: row['name'], code: row['code'])`.

Comment: it now has other error: `ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError in CoursesController#import`  `unknown attribute: Name`

Comment: `Name` should be lower case, shouldn't it? Check the resulting hash to make sure that all the keys are lower cased and correspond to your model.

Comment: i have no `Name` attribute. I can create new course with this: `Course.create(name: "Data Mining", code: "HT459DV01")`

Comment: The reason you have 'Name' and 'Code' is because your CSV file's columns are uppercase. Maybe you can try changing the name of the columns to lowercase.

Comment: So what's the issue now? You could try my updated answer too.

Comment: it just create the last row in csv file. i updated my answers for you.

Comment: I'm so sorry about the problem with `Name` attribute, it's my faults with content of csv file :( . I have used this code `Course.create!(name: row['name'], code: row['code'])` but not work, and i changed to `Course.create!(:name => row[0], :code => row[1])` by Dipak's suggestion and it work. Thanks for your help :)