# Rake Aborted: Can't mass-assign protected attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I try to `rake db:seed` a migration to import data via a seed helper.

One rake works (01_roles), but the other rake (02_conditions) says there are mass-assign protected attributes.

**fixtures/development/01_roles.rb**

```
SeedHelper.make_roles
```

**fixtures/development/02_conditions.rb**

```
SeedHelper.make_conditions
```

**seed_Helper.rb**

```
class SeedHelper
  include Singleton

  def self.make_roles
    file_path = "#{Rails.root}/db/roles.csv"
    RoleImporter::import(file_path)
  end

  def self.make_conditions
    file_path = "#{Rails.root}/db/conditions.csv"
    ConditionImporter::import(file_path)
  end
end
```

**model/condition.rb**

```
class Condition < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :condition, :bodypart, :description
end
```

I have a feeling it's calling the first fixture (01_roles) as there is a "description" variable in that file and it isn't calling that as an error:

```
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: condition, bodypart
```

**model/role.rb**

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :profession, :tag_list, :name
```

Where do I change the rake file or importer to read the correct file?

Comment: Have you checked this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13247149/cant-mass-assign-protected-attributes-when-import-data-from-csv-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer:

I needed to add `require 'condition_importer'` to importer.rb

Then in condition_importer.rb I had `Role.create!` instead of `Condition.create!` through duplicating the file:

```
class ConditionImporter
  def self.import(file_path)
    CSV.readlines(file_path, {:headers => :first_row, :encoding => 'UTF-8'}).each do |row|

  Condition.create!(
        condition:             row['Condition'],
        bodypart:              row['Bodypart'],
        description:           row['Description'])
      end
 end
end
```